# How to crash spooler service

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, print-server

Does anyone know how I can crash the spooler service manually?
I have a problem with some drivers crashing it randomly, and I want to do it manually so I can do some tests.

Comment: What sort of "crash" do you need? Does it need to terminate with a specific error code? Would `taskkill /f /im spoolsv.exe` work?

Comment: @jscott No, I need it to be the same way these faulty drivers do it.

Comment: @EliadTech then you're unlikely to get much help really - we don't have much to go on to suggest possible ways that faulty drivers are crashing the service!

Comment: @BE77Y If I'll post the faulty dll name and the relevant driver name would it help? I'm quite certain that this problem is not limited to my environment and to this specific driver..

Comment: @jscott Thanks, that's a good idea. I'll take a shot.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally delete my comment: If you have a known-corrupt .SHD/.SPL/.EMF file, you could try copying it to the spool directory, or otherwise generating the files as a "real" print job.

Comment: @jscott From what I've found the problem isn't related to a corrupted file sent to the printer. It looks like it's caused by some combination of loaded drivers, though I haven't been able yet to find which...

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Send an abnormally big (>1GB should do it) print file to it. Don't have a file that big? Whip up something in powershell along the lines of:

`PS C:\Users\BigHomie> 1..1000000000 | for-each {Get-Process | Out-File .\Desktop\test.txt -Append}`

Should do it, if not jus keep on truckin.

For best results, reduce the amount of available RAM the print spooler has to work with, that's always been a ringer in my environment.

Comment: Ah, how am I suppose to send a 1GB file? even Word couldn't open such a big file...

Answer (score 2):

Use [StressPrinters](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX109374) (https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX109374)

This tool is from Citrix, but it's to globally test printer driver, citrix or not on top of it.

> Many printer driver problems in Terminal Services/Remote Desktop
>   Services environments revolve around poor multi-threaded performance,
>   which in turn can cause print spooler instability. Problematic
>   multi-threaded performance is usually exposed when multiple users
>   connect to a Terminal Server simultaneously using the same printer
>   driver. Symptoms include the failure to autocreate client printers,
>   increased thread count of the printer spooler and/or Citrix Print
>   Manager services, and possibly the unresponsiveness and/or unexpected
>   termination of these services (stop responding).
>
> This tool can be used to simulate multiple sessions auto-creating
>   printers using the same printer driver.
>
> It can also be used to compare the following among various drivers:
>
> - CPU load incurred while creating a printer using a particular driver
> - Time required to successfully create a printer using a particular driver

[image]

Comment: Very nice. It's a start, but they say it's not fully testing the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply "end the task" on the spooler (spoolsv.exe) within the Task Manager that will initiate a "crash" of the spooler.

Comment: That's what jscott offered, but that's not a true test. I'm looking for a way to crash it like a driver does, and with some flexibility as to how to crash it.